# I do not want my updates to do an add if entity does not exist

Tags: azure

I want to be able to provide an UPDATE method to my users that will update the record they specify based on RowKey but it will NOT ADD it if the RowKey they pass in does not exist.

My reasoning is that if they mistakenly send in an invalid RowKey, I do not want them unknowingly ending up with a new entity vs. having updated the one they intended to update in the first place.

Here is the gist of the code I have (but that Adds/inserts the entity if it does not exist):

```
 ' p below is the entity obj (Inherits from TableServiceEntity) 
 ' PartitionKey and RowKey are set to values of entity to update 
     MyBase.AttachTo(_tableName, p)
     MyBase.UpdateObject(p)
     MyBase.SaveChangesWithRetries(Services.Client.SaveChangesWithOptions.Batch)
```

My issue is that I was expecting to get some exception thrown when SaveChanges executed and no entity with matching PK and RK was found. Instead the entity with the new PK, RK combination is added.

How can I structure my code so that only an UPDATE is done and no ADD if PK, RK is not existent?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you call the three argument version of AttachTo(), you will get the desired behavior.

```
MyBase.AttachTo(_tableName, p, "*");
```

But I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: This works as SaveChangesWithRetries now throws what appears to be a very general exception if the entity to update is not found ("An error occurred while processing this request." and Source field is set to "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient"). However, the key info I was after is in the InnerException where you find that Status Code = 404 (ResourceNotFound) and Source = "System.Data.Services.Client.: which is because the entity we were trying to update was not found.Therefore, I added a try catch where I catch

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching an error when you try to update and item that doesn't exists (I believe breischl is right about how to avoid that) the easiest thing to do would be to run a query to check if it does actually exist first.